# CSS is not working when I try to style html elements in a php page that includes another php page, which links to the css file

Tags: php, css, html, include

I have a header.php file that contains link to the css file...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
```

I have a categories.php page. My index. php page includes both header.php and categories.php, as shown below.

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    include('session.php');
?>
<h3>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h3> 
<table id="cat_feed">
    <tr>
        <td><?php include("categories.php"); ?></td>
        <td><?php include("feed.php"); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a style.css file that works fine and does affect index.php, but does not seem to affect when i add style to the css file.
The problem is that any new style changes donot affect how my index.php file looks.

Comment: did you use shift + F5 to load the page without cache?

Comment: no...but thanks...it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be to do with Varnish Cache, which is used to boost loading times of your website by caching assets (such as your stylesheet).

To disable Varnish Cache, add this line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

Comment: Thanks...but i have not worked with .htaccess files. How do i use one?

Comment: @Manish Have you located your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the cache that the browser stores.

Harder Way:
What you can do is, if you are using Google Chrome, then right click anywhere and click inspect. Once that is open, then you can right-click on the 'refresh' icon at the top left corner in chrome and click 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'.

Easier Way:
Install a chrome extension named 'Cache Killer' . While developing websites, just click on the icon of that extension and every reload would automagically delete the cache.

Another Way:
Open inspect tools same as before and click on 'Network' Tab and then click on 'Disable Cache'. And then whenever you will reload the site while having the inspect tools open, cache won't load

One more thing:
If you have cloudflare installed, then set it on dev mode because Cloudflare stores its own cache and no matter what it will reload that. Setting it to 'Dev' Mode or disabling it will resolve the issue